# Rails create a global variable accessible in set_trace_func and save it to file when server is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, metaprogramming

I want to automatically generate YARD style documentation for my functions (at-least the part that describes parameters and return values). So I am using set_trace_func.

Inside application.rb:

```
  set_trace_func proc { |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
    // my code goes here
  }

  class Application < Rails::Application
```

Inside set_trace_func I get a parameter binding, which gives me access to all the required data. I want to save this data to a set accessible globally(in all subsequent calls to set_trace_func) and then write this set into a file when the server is closed.

I know this is possible but I haven't been able to figure it out in quite a bit of time and would appreciate it if someone could direct me.

Comment: There's no code here at all which makes this question pretty hard to understand or even answer since context is important.

Comment: Allow me 10 minutes to remedy that.

Comment: @tadman I've made the changes and elaborated on my question.

Comment: You probably know already how `$global_variables` are defined. So what exactly is the difficulty here?

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to save any time at all. If it did you'd see it in more common use. Normally going through the code to every `def` and adding some detail is the most reliable way to do this.

Comment: I can see how determining "when server is closed" can be difficult. Without needing to integrate into the server's lifecycle, what you can do is dump the data periodically, while the server is still active.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, right on both counts. It already figured that the only way is to write all the data in a file, but there's probably a better way. Also I thought that a gem for this would exist, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @tadman Think 2 million lines of undocumented code with a lot of bad practices mixed in, conventions broken etc. If I could just get the line "@params arg_name [ArgClass] arg_example" on the head of every function, It would be great. Later someone could just add some description when they touch that code"

Comment: @AchyutRastogi I hope you have 500 interns to help with that. There's really no way to do this automatically. If your code is that chaotic I'd bet there's argument names like `x` and `array` which are as close to meaningless as possible.